# Where are the main collections of digitized Buddhist art online?

Tags: reference-request, art

I have found the [himalayanart.org](https://www.himalayanart.org/items/34832) website, which has the kind of art I am looking for, things like religious paintings, mandalas, etc. Where are the most digitized high-res buddhist art records kept online?

Comment: Maybe in a category related lesser to Buddhism then to art? At least here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the U.S. government's [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/search/?fa=subject:buddhas).

For e.g. you can download a 16MB JPEG file of the [Gandhara Scroll](https://www.loc.gov/item/2018305008) or 2MB sized JPEG of [South Korean Buddhist Rock Carvings](https://www.loc.gov/item/2021670679/).